# Trouble getting odeINT to accept equations generated by a loop

Tags: python, loops, differential-equations, odeint

I want to use Python's odeINT to integrate multiple sets of equations that are generated by a loop.  The equations are all coupled and so must be integrated simultaneously, via one call to odeINT.  The problem is that the initial conditions ("y0") must be a list of lists or a matrix (rather than simply a list).  odeINT gives this error: "Initial condition y0 must be one-dimensional".  I am wondering how to work around this.  Here is an example of the code; thanks so much for any ideas.

```
class network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i_range = 3
        ## INITIAL CONDITIONS WILL BE A LIST OF LISTS. 
        ## THIS IS THE SOURCE OF odeINT's ERROR.
        self.init = [[] for i in range(self.i_range)]  
        for i in range(0,self.i_range):
            self.init[i].append(-50.+0.1*(random.random()))
            self.init[i].append(1.+1.*(random.random()))

        self.Tfinal = 10  # final time   
        self.dt = 1.    # time step

    def eqns(self, x, t):
        a, b = x
        dadt = zeros_like(a)
        dbdt = zeros_like(b)
        for i in range (0,i_range):
            dadt[i] = np.cos(b[i])
            dbdt[i] = np.sin(a[i])
        return dadt, dbdt

    def run(self):
        self.times = sp.arange(0,self.Tfinal,self.dt)
        self.sim = odeint(self.eqns,self.init,self.times)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
a,b = reshape(x,(2,-1))
```

to split the flat vector and

```
return reshape((dadt,dbdt), -1)
```

to recombine them into a flat array. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

---

More concretely, and playing with some of the list functionality of python, in the initialization do

```
a = [ -50. + 0.1*random.random() for _ in range(self.i_range) ]
b = [   1. + 1.0*random.random() for _ in range(self.i_range) ]
self.init = np.reshape((a,b), -1)
```

and the ode function becomes

```
def eqns(self, x, t):
    a, b = np.reshape(x,(2,-1))
    dadt = [ np.cos(bb) for aa,bb in zip(a,b) ]
    dbdt = [ np.sin(aa) for aa,bb in zip(a,b) ]
    return np.reshape((dadt,dbdt), -1)
```

This should be sufficient to get some result. You might want to transform `self.sim` into a list of pairs of lists to regain the structure of the problem, however there you have to work, as there are now 2 "large" dimensions to provide.

```
np.reshape(self.sim, (self.times.size,2,-1))
```

could work as a first step..

Comment: Thanks so much for this help.  I have implemented that in the eqns section, but I do not understand  how to reformat the initial conditions ("self.init").  As you can see in the example code above, I have two separate locations for a loop through the ICs (near top, in "self") and through the variables (below, in "eqns").  Should I try to incorporate a single loop for both?

Comment: I ask about combining loops because: when I loop more than once, I get the error: "too many values to unpack".  This is because, say I loop twice: It first sees 4 ICs, then it sees that "eqns" calls just 2 variables - before it knows to loop twice through them.

Comment: Is your intention that the first value is a[i] and the second b[i]? Then start `init` as `[ [], [] ]` as pair of two lists and append to the first and second. Or use local variables `a0=[]; b0=[];`, append to those and combine them via `self.init = reshape((a0,b0), -1)`, so that all flattening and structuring happens with the same methods. The state vector for integration has to be a flat list or vector in all instances where it is passed to the integrator.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my intention.  When I create a list of lists, the error is that y0 (the initial conditions) must be one-dimensional.  When I append to local variables and then combine, as you suggest, I get: "too many values to unpack".

Comment: So, basically, odeINT requires the ICs to be a one-D list, and it does not understand how to relegate every two entries appropriately, even given your framework.  Could you possibly embed your changes into my code above, so I can understand exactly what you mean?

Comment: I added the changes to the initialization and the ODE function. In principle it should work, however I have only tested the validity of the single lines, not of the whole code.